# Password protect sheets from viewing

Tags: excel, password-protection

I'm not sure if this is possible, as Google did not find what I'm after.

I have an excel spreadsheet that has many sheets. I am putting the spreadsheet on our server, so everyone can access it. However, I don't want all the sheets in that same spreadsheet to be available for everyone to view. For example, sheet 2 has sales figures, so I'd like sheet 2 to be only viewable by the sales staff. However, sheet 3 has the programmer tasks, and I would like this sheet to be accessible to the sales staff, as well as the programmer.

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, or if there's a way at all, but here's an idea. Is there a way I can password protect all sheets with different passwords, and have the users to put passwords before they can actually view the sheet? Currently, I can only protect the cells from changes with password protection, but they still can see the sheets.

Comment: https://excel.tips.net/T001952_Protecting_Individual_Worksheets_by_User.html

Comment: Also note with VBA you can set sheets to either [`Hidden` or `Very Hidden`](http://www.excel-university.com/make-an-excel-worksheet-very-hidden/)

Comment: Thanks @jmoon for your link. That helps heaps as well as this link https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/910802-macor-help.html&source=gmail&ust=1504041595773000&usg=AFQjCNG4Mi0_ZW1AeM81AngHq_6zWipspw